# Auth0 authorization for resources with certain IDs in Angular2/4 and Web API 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, auth0

I have a Content Management System that allows editing of 3D Maps. I want to authorize on a per-user-basis, such that a user can only PUT/DELETE/GET a certain MapId if:

- The user owns the map
- The user is an admin

I've looked at scopes, but these feel like the wrong approach since a scope of "edit:maps" can't differ MapIds, only if the user can edit *any* maps.

Another approach would be using auth0 Rules, like this:

```
function (user, context, callback) {    

    var allAuthorizedMapIdsForUser = someExternalDbCall();

    context.idToken['https://authorizedMapids.com'] = allAuthorizedMapIdsForUser;

    callback(null, user, context);
}
```

but I'm unsure on how to implement and use this in the ASP NET Web API 2.

The third and probably most redundant approach would be to implement manual authorization in every API method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMap(int mapId)
    {
        var userId = //somehow get userId

                            // Checks some DB-table if user has MapId or is admin
        bool isAuthorized = this.IsUserAuthorizedForMapId(mapId, userId);

        if (!isAuthorized)
            return Unauthorized();

        // ..perform GET
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

what i can suggest to you is to create a custom [Authorize] decoration for AspNetIdentiy wich is not Role-Based but `User-Based`...

for example (assuming you're using AspNET Identity for Webapi like this: `http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/` ...or any other tutorial)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)] 
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// aallowed ids you opass external or if you prefer you can deo a query in the AuthorizeCore method
    /// </summary>
   public  string IDS { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if the user is authenticated and has the
    /// correct role to access a particular view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

           var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();//get current userid
            ApplicationUserManager UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();//get usermanage

            var IDSAllowed = IDS.Split(",").ToList();

            bool isAuthorized = IDSAllowed.Any()?  IDSAllowed.Contains(userId) : false; //if you prefer you can deo a query on DB to retrive allowed IDS

        if (!isAuthorized)
            return Unauthorized();

        return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotAuthorized" };
    } 
}
```

and then you can use it in your Controllers as

```
[CustomAuthorize(IDS = "1,2,9")]
     [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMap(int mapId)
    {

    }
```

Something like this .. hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would work if the IDs were known before hand, but I'm looking for a more dynamic approach since the users can create maps on their own and therefore the IDs need to be fetched at runtime/method-call. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way though. My concern is that the user can maliciously change the map id in the Angular 2 front end, and can therefore delete any map they want. I'm reckoning I should look into front end security instead and before loading any map do an API call to check if the user is authorized on that particular map by UserID in JWT-token.